# Angular POST to ASP.NET MVC: object properties are NULL

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc

In my case I am trying to `POST` data from Angular (v15) to ASP.NET on the .NET Framework 4.72.

Client side:

```
var name = this.inName;
var queue = new Queue();
queue.QueueId = 6;
queue.CustomerFullName =  name;
queue.Status = 5;
var d = new Date();
const data = JSON.stringify({'queue':queue});
const headers = new HttpHeaders();
const dataType = 'json';
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
let options = { headers: headers };
var url = 'https://localhost:44392/Queue/AddQueue';
this.http.post(url, data, options).subscribe(
  (response) => {
    console.log(response);
    if (response) {
      var x = response;
    }
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log('Error: ', error);
  }
);
```

Server side:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddQueue(Queue queue)
{
     // ...
}
```

This is the payload:

```
{"queue":{"QueueId":6,"CustomerFullName":"fjnsjtn","Status":5}}
```

And preview:

```
{
  "QueueId": 1025,
  "CustomerFullName": null,
  "DueIn": null,
  "Status": null
}
```

What is my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using

```
const data = JSON.stringify({'queue':queue});
```

Post the Queue object, not a string and get rid of the headers.

```
this.http.post(url, queue)
```

Or try decorating the API with a FromBody attribute

```
public JsonResult AddQueue([FromBody]Queue queue)
```